# Is there a way to make just one row of a Vaadin Table editable?

Tags: java, vaadin

is there maybe a way to just make one row of the Vaadin Table editable?
i'm a starter and i searched everywhere, Either I did not understand the answers or it was not what i wanted.

Could anyone put a small sample please or guide me in someway ?

TinQ...

Comment: not the answer to your question, but this is the default behaviour of the `Grid`.

Comment: thanks cfrick, i've already thought about `Grid`, but unfortunately in out Project, they are using a Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can achieve both results with a customized TableFieldFactory set for the table. If you return null in createField method, the cell will be displayed like in non-editable table."

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Source:https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/189088

Comment: tnx @switcher05

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague but once you have the table created and properties assigned you can attach a Value Change Listener that gets the value of the selected row. I open the data into a new form for editing.

```
private Table<Ticket> list = new Table<>(Ticket.class)
list.addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent -> adjustActionButtonState());

private void adjustActionButtonState() {
        boolean hasSelection = list.getValue() != null;
        edit.setEnabled(hasSelection);
        delete.setEnabled(hasSelection);
    }
```

Comment: not actually, what i need is a way to just make a row of Table editable. in this case the whole Table will Editable. i hope that i could have tell it clear.